# React, making an element glide smoothly in response to mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The following code renders two panels, containing two images. Scrolling up and down zooms in and out. As the mouse moves (while the image is zoomed) the image is transformed in a way that follows the mouse cursor. Note: the containing `PaintingPanel` element has the style `overflow: hidden` so you can only see the portion of the image contained within `PaintingPanel`. Everything works well.

Problem: I wanted to make the mouse following slightly "glide", I applied a `transition` style to see if this could work. It does not really work in React, it is very jolty. The transform only updates when my mouse is stopping.

Question: Is there a way to make the movement of the image following the mouse "glidey"? E.g. moving the mouse causes a transform that is delayed slightly behind the mouse movement, maybe with some sort of proportional speed of movement depending on the distance between the final and current position of the image.

```
// import { useState } from 'react'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import PaintingPanel, {PaintingPanelProps, PaintingPosition} from './PaintingPanel';


const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [paintingPosition, setPaintingPosition] = useState<PaintingPosition>({
    zoomRatio: 1,
    xFraction: 0,
    yFraction: 0
  })

  const paintingName = 'test';

  const zoomPainting = (e: WheelEvent) => {
    const minZoomRatio = 1.0;
    const maxZoomRatio = 2.4;
    
    const newPaintingPosition = {...paintingPosition}

    const nextZoomRatio = newPaintingPosition.zoomRatio + -e.deltaY/1000;

    newPaintingPosition.zoomRatio = Math.min(Math.max(nextZoomRatio, minZoomRatio), maxZoomRatio)

    setPaintingPosition(newPaintingPosition)
  }

  function createFollowMouseOnPainting(panelId: string) {
    return (e: MouseEvent) => {
      const newPaintingPosition = {...paintingPosition}

      //Containing panel element
      const paintingPanel: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementById(panelId);

      const rect = paintingPanel.getBoundingClientRect();

      //target element dimensions 
      const targetWidth = paintingPanel.clientWidth;
      const targetHeight = paintingPanel.clientHeight;

      newPaintingPosition.xFraction = (e.clientX - rect.left)/targetWidth
      newPaintingPosition.yFraction = (e.clientY - rect.top)/targetHeight

      setPaintingPosition(newPaintingPosition)
    }
  }

  //Translate the position of the mouse to a tranasform value for the painting (linear interpolation)
  const xTransform = 100*((0.5 - paintingPosition.xFraction) * (1-(1/paintingPosition.zoomRatio)));
  const yTransform = 100*((0.5 - paintingPosition.yFraction) * (1-(1/paintingPosition.zoomRatio)));

  const paintingImgStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    transform: `scale(${paintingPosition.zoomRatio}) translateX(${xTransform}%) translateY(${yTransform}%)`,
  }
  
  console.log(paintingImgStyle)

  const panelOneProps: PaintingPanelProps = {
    paintingName: paintingName,
    isDiff: false,
    paintingImgStyle,
    zoomPainting,
    createFollowMouseOnPainting
  }

  const panelTwoProps: PaintingPanelProps = {
    paintingName: paintingName,
    isDiff: true,
    paintingImgStyle,
    zoomPainting,
    createFollowMouseOnPainting
  }

  const panelOne = <PaintingPanel {...panelOneProps} />
  const panelTwo = <PaintingPanel {...panelTwoProps} />



  return (
    <>
    <div id='panel-container'>
      {panelOne}
      {panelTwo}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```